# Get-Date.ToString('r') returning incorrect time (GMT instead of local timezone)

Tags: powershell

PowerShell is not showing the time correctly and is ignoring my local time zone - it is currently 00:20 (at +2 GMT), but on getting the time shows the local time  (00:20) but incorrectly prints GMT.

Checking on the server on which the script is running, and the timezone and local time are set correctly.

Have I done something wrong or is this a bug?

```
$scriptStartDate = Get-Date
Write-Host "time is $($scriptStartDate.ToString('r'))"
# above line prints 'Sun, 14 Apr 2013 00:20:00 GMT'
# this is wrong as wrong timezone, it should be 'Sun, 14 Apr 2013 00:20:00 E.Europe'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is up to you to make sure the time is in UTC.  You can do that like so:

```
[DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString('r')
```

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) on this format say the following:

> Formatting does not modify the value of the DateTime; therefore, you
>   must adjust the value to GMT before formatting.